# How to calculate popularity based on some known factors

Tags: algorithm, popularity, scoring

I've got a list of movies for each of which the following factors are known:

- Number of people that wish to watch the movie in future
- Number of people that have watched the movie
- Number of people that have enjoyed the movie
- Number of people that watched and disliked the movie
- Number of comments on the movie
- Number of page hits (directly or from search engines) for the movie page

So based on the above factors, I am looking for a way to calculate popularity for each of the movies. Is there any known formula or algorithm to calculate the popularity value in such case? Preferred algorithms are those which provide a more efficient way to update the previously calculated popularity value for each item.

Comment: Take a look at the netflix challenge. Stratified SVD appeared to be the solution. BTW do you only have aggregated counts, or also the indiviual votes/links/etc ?

Comment: @wildplasser: The netflix challenge doesn't rank popularity of movies, it is a recommender system - it ranks how good a movie ranks an individual - based on how he ranked other movies and how other users ranked their movies... Not sure how it can be applied here. :|

Comment: @Meysam Well, there are infinite ways to do it, a simple sum can do the trick, or a weighted sum (give each component a factor). You should probably apply normalization for each feature before doing any of it (because number of comments is likely to be significantly lower then number of watches, and you don't want the first to be negligable comparing to the second). If you are willing to give manual grades to a sample of movies, you might use supervised machine learning (linear regression, for instance) to address this problem.

Comment: Me neither. The comment was intended as a hint on how others tacke a *similar* problem. If the op only has the counts (and other aggregates) linear regression is the only way to go. Could be stratified in some way.

Comment: @wildplasser I have individual votes.

Comment: Than take a look at the netfix challenge solutions. There appear to be some incremental SVD matrix-update methods for the AbA' sandwich

Answer (score 2):

There are basically infinite ways to do what you are after, depending on how important each factor is.

First, you will need to **normalize the data**. One way to do it is assume each feature is [distributed normally](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), and find the standard deviation and mean of each feature. (your features are number of people watched the movie, number of people enjoyed the movie,...).

Once you have the sd (standard deviation) and mu (mean), you can easily transform the features for each movie to the standard form using `norm = (value-mu)/sd`.

- The estimator for the mean (mu) is the simple average: `sum(x_i) / n`
- The estimator for the standard deviation (sd) is `sd = sqrt(Sum((x_i - mu)^2) / (n-1))`

Once you have normalized your data, you can simply **define the rating as a weighted sum**, where each feature will get a boost according to how significant it is:

```
a1 * #watched + a2 * #liked + ....
```

---

If you don't know what the weight is, but willing to manually give grade to a set of movies, you might use supervised learning to find (a1,a2,...,an) for you using [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression).

Answer (score 1):

There is no correct answer, but I think we should try to model it as close to reality as possible.
Let's consider the following:
      `P1=Proportion of people who watched and enjoyed it`
      `P2=Proportion of people who disliked the movie`
      `P3=Proportion of people who watched and would like to see again`
      `P4=People who will watch it later but haven't seen it yet`
The number of comments simply can't tell how good a movie is, though it can tell how popular it is.Sure.You could leverage the amount of positive and negative comments if its possible to segregate so(possibly by up-votes and down-votes), or you could just use the number of comments as such(C).

Number of page hits should usually give a good indication of the popularity of the movie, so we should give it a good weight in our algorithm.Moreover we should give recent page hits more weight than say page hits of over a year ago.So try and keep the count of page hits in the last three days(N3), in the last week(N7), in the last month(N30) and in the last year(N365), and everything else(Nrest).

You come up with an algorithm using the factors I mentioned.
[Try to use weighted average and variations of Horner's rule for quick updates.Good Luck.]